# Re-compute Computed Property With Getter When Navigated to a Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have the following component assigned to the url `/A`:

```
export default {

  data () {
    return {
      dummyVariableToUpdateDays: true
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.dummyVariableToUpdateDays = !this.dummyVariableToUpdateDays
  },
  computed: {
    days () {
    this.dummyVariableToUpdateDays = !this.dummyVariableToUpdateDays
      return this.$store.getters.getToDoItemsWithinRange.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(b.onlyDate) - new Date(a.onlyDate)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

`days` value is properly computed in my first visit to this url. However, if I visit the `url A` second time, it is computed again and the getter function inside the computed property still gives the old value (which is actually changed in another component).

Comment: You mean your state is changing on route change but your getter still provides old state?

Comment: no there is no problem with getter. getter (thus days compute-method) is not executed in my second visit.

Comment: Can you for testing purpose tell me what is the change? is it a change in value of an element or the length of array is getting changed?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal you were right ! The computed method is executed well every time i visit the url but my getter still provides the old state....

Comment: Okay, so is what kind of change is this? change in value of an element, or new elements are getting added?

Comment: changing value of an object with a lot of properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are noticing the said behavior is because vue doesn't pick up changes made to an element of an array on an index, this is documented [here](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/).

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method arr.$set(index, value) which is just syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1, value).

As mentioned above, you can try using:

```
arr.$set(index, value)
```

or

```
arr.splice(index, 1, value)
```

---

[Further reading](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)